# Angular 5.2 -> 6.0 migration - angular.json not replacing angular-cli.json

Tags: json, angular, migration, angular-cli

So I've been following the [official documentation](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=5.2-6.0) to upgrade from Angular 5.2 to Angular 6.0 (I'm migrating an app to Angular 13).

When I run the command `NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/cli@6` I've got no errors whatsoever:

```
$ NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/cli@6
npx : 336 installé(s) en 36.906s
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 100 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
UPDATE package.json (4717 bytes)
✔ Packages successfully installed.
```

This command is supposed to replace/migrate the `angular-cli.json` file to a new file called `angular.json` but when I look at my files I still have the old `angular-cli.json` file and not the new one.

I've tried a lot of suggestions found here and there on the internet and SO such as installing/reinstalling angular-cli, cleaning my cache, I tried to revert to a working commit, I tried the `ng update @angular/cli --from={blah} --migrate-only` command but nothing seems to work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Note : sometimes, the easiest way for such huge migrations is to start a new project from scratch and copy paste the src folder. Code changes might be small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in the end by emptying my `.npmrc` file and running the command again